# how to apply the id to form dynamically in phonegap android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, autocomplete, cordova

I am creating an app in which I am using an autocomplete view the list is created dynamically in the js file. Know what i want is if i create more than one  autocompete i want to apply and different id to the input type='search' which is created by the jquery mobile autocomplete I tried to apply the id to the input field but whats happening is its apply the sane id to all the input field where role='search'. But I want to give different id to each input field where role ='search '. 
Here is the js code for autocomplete:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#myPage", function() {
$( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
    var $ul = $( this ),
        $input = $( data.input ),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html( "" );
    if ( value && value.length > 1 ) {

         html +="<li >Xyz</li>";
         html +="<li >Abc</li>";

         $ul.html( html );
         $ul.listview( "refresh" );
         $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
         $.mobile.activePage.find('input[data-type="search"]').attr('id','namesearch');

    }

    $("ul>li").click(function(){

        var textval=$(this).text();
        $('#namesearch').val(textval);
        $.mobile.activePage.find("[data-role=listview]").children().addClass('ui-screen-hidden');

    });
});

$("#autocomplete1").on("listviewbeforefilter",function(e,data){
    var $ul = $(this),
        $input=$(data.input),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html('');
    if(value && value.length >1) {
        html +="<li>efg</li>";
        html +="<li>hijk</li>";
        $ul.html(html);
        $ul.listview("refresh");
        $ul.trigger("updatelayout");

         $('#autocomplete').parent('div').find('input[data-type="search"]').attr('id','namesearch1');
    }
    $("ul>li").click(function(){
        var textval1 = $(this).text();
        $("#namesearch1").val(textval1);
        $.mobile.activePage.find("[data-role=listview]").children().addClass('ui-screen-hidden');
    });
});});
```

here is the html code ul is created:

```
<ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Find a city..."  data-filter-theme="d">
            </ul>

            <ul id="autocomplete1" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Find a city..."  data-filter-theme="d">
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a simple change to made I didnt find before asking the Question. 
I just change the code 
form:

```
 $.mobile.activePage.find('input[data-type="search"]').attr('id','namesearch');
```

to this:

```
 $.mobile.activePage.find('input[placeholder="Find city..."]').attr('id','namesearch');
```

before i was finding the data-type because of this it was applying id to all the fields having the data type =search .