# How to set limit to jQuery mobile autocomplete to display on 10 results

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, autocomplete, cordova-2.0.0

I am creating an app in which I want to implement the JQM autocomplete. I had created the autocomplete it just the demo before implementing it to project.

What I want to know is how to set the limit that it will show only 10 listview results and not more than that.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18566107/2307391) is a link to the code of the autocomplete.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

slice your result

```
var result=//your result in array




results.slice(0, 10)); // by this only 10 results come
```

reference [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

Comment: I am new to this can tell me how to do this by giving example

Comment: if you will see reference then you can know about it and talk about your problem  first get your result in array then by slice it make array of 10 element now i am set a demo for u to understand the slice

Comment: hey did saw the code that i had written for the auto complete because the example which you had give is for jquery ui aucomplete and i am using jquery mobile autocomplete.

Comment: u can apply your logic here any way i will set for mobile

Comment: i will wait for your replay when your done with logic in mobile

Comment: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/autocomplete/ i read this in this the best solution is you will set your result limiy up to 10 in response side if you get your result by ajax then on server side apply limit 10 if not then in here you apply at client side slice